# How to identify users who previously had an older app version

Tags: commcare

I am trying to configure a screen that should only display for users who previously had an app version below a certain threshold (for example, for users who had an app version <= 100). This will be used to display information about an update to users who were previously using an old version of the app.

1) How can I determine whether the user previously had an older version of the app?

2) How can I configure the screen to only display for users that previously had an older version of the app?

Answer (score 1):

So your info screen would likely be a separate module/form.  Once that form is filled out, it should save a case property to the user case.  Let's call that property version_used and set that to "2" to indicate that that user has seen the instructions for version 2.

Then you would put module filters on all the modules such that if version_used < 2 or version_used = "", then show the info module but no other modules.  If instead version_used = 2, don't show the info module and do show all the other modules.  (You would have to decide what happens if somehow a user goes back a version and version_used > 2 just to make sure no one gets blocked, but we don't expect that to happen).

In the future, when you make version 3 of the app, you could change the module display conditions to have 3 everywhere there is a 2.

Comment: Hi Jen, thanks for your thoughts on a solution! In this particular case, I'm looking to include a screen within an existing form that has been modified. There are two reasons for this: 1) Users won't know to look for updates in a separate form/module, and 2) The changes are more easily understood within the context of a specific form. Can you think of any ways to set this up from within an existing form?

Comment: Ok, no problem.  You would use the same solution as the one above, but your display condition would be on questions in the form rather than on a module.